# Using .delegate to wrap content loaded via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iframe

I've built a simple social network using Buddypress, where any new status updates posted after page load can be loaded in via AJAX. To make timeline videos responsive (within iframes), I'm using the following:

jQuery

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $( ".activity-inner p iframe" ).wrap( "<div class='embed-container'></div>" );
});
```

HTML (default BuddyPress output)

```
<div class="activity-inner">
  <div class="embed-container">
    <p><iframe width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gvOx9VMZtBA?feature=oembed"></iframe></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when new posts with video embeds are loaded via AJAX, this is no longer applied to any new instances of an iframe. From what I understand, this may be achievable using `.delegate`, but I'm open to any other suggestions if my logic is a bit off. If anyone could shed some light on how I can wrap new iframes loaded in via AJAX with the code above I'd be massively appreciative.

*** UPDATE ***

I've modified a pretty simple approach to doing this with PHP so that any embeds generated are wrapped at source using the following snippet in 'functions.php':

```
add_filter('oembed_dataparse','oembed_add_wrapper',10,3);
function oembed_add_wrapper($return, $data, $url) {
  return "<div class='embed-container'>{$return}</div>";
}
```

Thanks to @Tomalak for another working solution via https://github.com/kapetan/jquery-observe (below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three different ways to go about this, depending on how the new elements arrive on your page.

1. **If you control the Ajax requests**, then wrap the your iframes they return yourself, in the success callback of the Ajax request. This is the simplest solution.
2. **If a third-party library controls the Ajax requests** and that library offers an event system (see the documentation of that library), then react to those events and wrap the iframes when they occur. This is analogous to option 1.
3. **If a third-party library controls the Ajax requests** and this library does NOT offer an event system (highly unlikely), i.e. you have no control over when new elements appear on your page, then (and only then!) you can resort to listening to DOM changes, like shown below.

---

If you decided that option #3 is **the only way** to solve your problem:

You can use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to monitor the DOM for changes. This is [supported in all major browsers now](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver).

Be sure to read through the docs *first*, so you have an idea what they can do, how they are used and what things like `record` or `childList` mean in the code below.

There is a convenient jQuery plugin on GitHub that wraps mutation observers in the jQuery usage pattern: https://github.com/kapetan/jquery-observe

With that you can do things like this:

```js
$(function () {
    // helper to find all unwrapped iframes and wrap them
    function enhancePost() {
        $(this).find("iframe").filter(function () {
            return $(this).parent(".embed-container").length === 0;
        }).wrap("<div class='embed-container'></div>");
    }

    // listen to DOM changes on the feedContainer
    $('#feedContainer').observe('childlist', '.activity-inner', function (record) {
        // a "#feedContainer > .activity-inner" has been added or removed
        console.log(record);
        $(record.addedNodes).each(enhancePost);
    });


    // example button and page init  
    $("#add").click(function () {
        $('<div class="activity-inner"></div>')
        .text("Post #" + ($(".activity-inner").length + 1))
        .append("<iframe></iframe>")
        .appendTo("#feedContainer");
    });
  
    $("#feedContainer .activity-inner").each(enhancePost);
});
```

```css
#feedContainer {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#feedContainer .activity-inner {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#feedContainer .embed-container {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
iframe {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: #efefef;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kapetan/jquery-observe/master/jquery-observe.js"></script>

<div id="feedContainer">
  <div class="activity-inner">Post #1 <iframe></iframe></div>
  <div class="activity-inner">Post #2</div>
</div>

<button id="add">Add activity</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @Tomalak - looks ideal. I'll read through the docs and test your response, then update/accept the answer.

Comment: @GraemeBryson As I said, don't use this code when you can go with option #1 or #2. It's absolute overkill unless option #3 is the only one you have.